# Regarding the סעודה in a פורים משולש,‎ how does the שלחן ערוך understand the ברייתא in מגילה not to be arguing on the ירושלמי?‎

Tags: halacha-theory, purim, meal-seudah

The גמרא in מגילה דף ד ע"ב to ה ע"א discusses the דינים of a פורים on שבת brings a ברייתא (marking the Amoritic interpolation according to “רש"י ד"ה ”אדרבה‎‏):‎

> תניא נמי הכי אף על פי שאמרו כפרים מקדימין ליום הכניסה גובין בו ביום ומחלקין בו ביום [אף על פי שאמרו אדרבה משום דאמרו הוא אלא הואיל ואמרו שכפרים מקדימין ליום הכניסה גובין בו ביום ומחלקין בו ביום] מפני שעיניהם של עניים נשואות במקרא מגילה אבל שמחה אינה נוהגת אלא בזמנה

The ירושלמי says that in a פורים משולש we push the סעודה to Sunday because the מגילה said בית דין must "make" a day of שמחה,‎ משמע it can't be שבת which was already שמח.‎ But my understanding was that it is the דרך of the שלחן ערוך not to פסקן the ירושלמי over a בבלי,‎ and certainly not over
תנאים,‎ so how can one understand this ברייתא other than as paskening that the פורים סעודה should be on שבת?

Comment: As below, this isn't a question on the yerushalmi about purim meshulash. But it is a very good question against the Acharonim who innovated that places with a doubt which day of Purim is theirs need only read the megilla both days but can celebrate on only one. If anything the talmud (in other places too) indicates clearly the exact opposite. An early megilla reading may plausibly be acceptable but partying must be in the right time.

Answer (score 2):

This *beraita* is not discussing the case of Purim falling on *shabbat*.

It's talking about villagers who are not able to read *megillah* on the 14th (on a weekday). Instead, they read on the previous market day (Monday or Thursday) and give out *matanot la-evyonim* on that day. However, they rejoice on the 14th.

Comment: The משנה does discuss the case of a Friday reading that gets advanced to a Thursday,‎ but this ברייתא is brought right after רבה and רב יוסף give reasons for the גזירה against reading the מגילה on שבת,‎ and the ברייתא is introduced with תניא נמי הכי which introduces a ברייתא bringing support for the previous statement. ‎So how can the ברייתא be unrelated to the previous סוגיא?‎ Also,‎ isn't "שמחה" how the פורים סעודה is referred to in תנאים?‎

Comment: The תניא נמי הכי is only brought to back up רב יוסף's argument that עיניהם של עניים נשואות במקרא מגילה. Just like in this ברייתא the villagers have to give מתנות לאביונים on their early megillah-reading day, so too, if purim falls on shabbos, when we can't give מתנות לאביונים, so megillah also can't be on shabbos but must instead be on the same day as מתנות לאביונים.

Comment: Regarding the final line in your comment, yes שמחה here refers to the seuda. But again, it's not talking about purim on shabbos

Comment: I appreciate the time for your answers.‎ I see that your reading of the text makes sense.‎ I reached out to two acquaintances,‎ one was a close student of Rav Sheinberg for several decades,‎ and another who is a posek and rosh kollel in the Mattersdorf area who was a longtime student of R Moshe Shapiro.‎ Both told me that the אחרונים and poskim understand this barisa to be a reference to Purim on Shabbos,‎ but disagree on whether it is limited to the כפרים,‎ like the שלכן ערוך holds,‎ or whether it applies to everyone,‎ as hold some אחרונים the משנה ברורה‎ brings.

Comment: In deference to the fact that your explanation also fits the text,‎ I'm not going to mark the question answered according to their explanation,‎ but because it seems like there is a צד to say like them,‎ I'm going to hold off on accepting the your answer also,‎ but I really appreciate your time and the dialog.‎ Wishing you a good שבת!

Comment: @ak0000 You’re very welcome. If you can source these acharonim or poskim whom you’re quoting here (or even better - write them up an as an alternative answer) I would be very interested to see them. א גוט שבת!

Comment: I'll try to reach out again and see if it is discussed explicitly (as opposed to just being two rival ways of understanding how the בית יוסף understood the ברייתא) -‎ I know the משנה ברורה cites the מהר"ל חביב as paskening you do have the סעודה on שבת because he holds this is the פסק of the בבלי,‎ which I was told was from this ברייתא but I didn't see him inside to know if he says so explicitly ("מ"ב תרפ״ח ד"ה "ואין עושין וכו) – I wonder where else he could think the בבלי is paskening from if not there.

Comment: @ak0000 Yeah I started looking into it and מהרלב״ח does quote the language of שמחה אינה נוהגת אלא בזמנה to support his position. Maybe I’ll add to my answer one of these days, or you (or anyone else) is welcome to write their own

Comment: interesting thanks,‎ I'm not sure I have access to the original מהרלב״ח outside of what's quoted in the MB so good to know.‎

Comment: @ak0000 You can see the teshuva here https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1199&st=&pgnum=37&hilite=

Comment: ‎k Thanks so much!